# Implementing Youtube Data API Videos: Insert in angular and ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, youtube-api

Looking for some direction in how to implement the youtube api in ionic/angular to upload videos to specific channel.

I'm trying to use this https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/upload_video.js

how can import it to typescript?

Answer (score 0):

you import it to typescript by finding the definetly typed version of the api e.g. for youtube api: `https://github.com/jhdrn/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/youtube/youtube.d.ts`
or `https://github.com/andrew-w-ross/typings-youtube-api-search/blob/master/youtube-api-search.d.ts`

Does this fit your needs?
If both of these don't work just insert a `<script></script>` tag with the source of your file and set a `declare const` variable in your class, but I don't recommend this way. As I think typescript thinks there is this declare variable which I do not need to evaluate, but the programmer says it will be there on runtime, you will not get shown any errors like misspelled functions etc.